# How to fill the second dropdown on the selection of first dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm implementing asp.net core project and I have a selectList that shows regions and after choosing a region from it, I want to fetch related data to a second dropdown that shows zones. Here is my code till now:

My edited code:

```
   public class OperatorViewModel {
 public IEnumerable<BuyWasteRequestViewModel> BuyWasteRequestVM { get; set; }
 [Required] public string SelectedRegionID { get; set; }
 [Required]
 public string SelectedZoneID { get; set; }
 public string SelectedRegionText { get; set; }
 public string SelectedZoneText { get; set; } 
}
```

And Here my view:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.OperatorViewModel
    
     <form method="post">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRegionID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RegionId, "select", new { @style = "position: absolute; width: 42%; padding: 2%; border: 1px solid #ced4da; border-radius: 3px; right: 4.5rem; height: 2.35rem;" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedRegionText)
    
    
    <select id="SelectedZoneID" name="@Html.NameFor(c=>c.SelectedZoneID)" class="form-control statesSelect" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ZoneID,"Id", "Name"))">
                                    <option value='0'>select</option>
     </select>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedZoneText)
    </form>
    
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#SelectedRegionID")
                .change(function () {
    
                    var id = $(this).val();
                    $("#SelectedRegionText").attr("value", $("#SelectedRegionID option:selected").text());
                    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetZones", "Operator")/' + id, function (data) {
                        //delete the options of $("#SelectedZoneID") and add new options
                        $("#SelectedZoneID").empty();
                        $("#SelectedZoneID").append('<option value="0">select</option>');
                         $.each(data, function (value, text) {
                             $("#SelectedZoneID").append('<option value="' + text.value + '">' + text.text + '</option>');
                    });
            });
                });
    
    
            $("#SelectedZoneID").change(function () {
                $("#SelectedZoneText").attr("value", $("#SelectedZoneID option:selected").text());
            });
    
            $("#SelectedRegionID")
          .change(function() {
              $('#SelectedRegionText').val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
    
         });
```

In my controller:

```
public class OperatorController : Controller
    {
        private readonly WasteAPIContext _context;

        public OperatorController(WasteAPIContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(OperatorViewModel buywastervm)
        {
            
            return BuildIndexModel(buywastervm.SelectedRegionID, buywastervm.SelectedRegionText, buywastervm.SelectedZoneID, buywastervm.SelectedZoneText);
        }

public IActionResult BuildIndexModel(string selectedRegionID, string selectedRegionText,string selectedZoneID, string selectedZoneText){
 ViewData["RegionId"] = new SelectList(_context.Region, "Id", "Name", "select");

 ViewData["ZoneId"] = new SelectList(_context.Zone.Where(c => c.RegionId == selectedZoneID), "Id", "Name", "select");

 OperatorVM.BuyWasteRequestVM = bwrvm;
            OperatorVM.SelectedRegionID = selectedRegionID;
            OperatorVM.SelectedRegionText = selectedRegionText;
            OperatorVM.SelectedZoneID = selectedZoneID;
            OperatorVM.SelectedZoneText = selectedZoneText;

  return View(OperatorVM);
 }

public JsonResult GetZones(string ID)
        {
            
             List<SelectListItem> ZoneList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            var zones = _context.Zone.Where(c => c.RegionId == ID).Select(c => new
            {
                Value = c.Id,
                Text = c.Name
            }).ToList();

            foreach (var item in zones)
            {
                SelectListItem slist = new SelectListItem();
                slist.Value = item.Value; /*0 + mvalue*/
                slist.Text = item.Text;
                ZoneList.Add(slist);
            }


            ViewData["ZoneId"] = new SelectList(_context.Zone.Where(c => c.RegionId == ID), "Id", "Name", "select");
            return Json(ZoneList);

        }
```

Now my problem is, I want after choosing my considering region from region selectlist and accordingly choosing an item from zone selectlist and then submitting the form, I have the ability to see all populated related zones to selected region displayed before submitting the form in zone selectlist. Right now, after submitting the form, I'm just able to see  item in zone selectlist. Moreover, I need after submitting the form, the user can see the selected item in zone list as the selected option. Now I can see the selected region in Region selectlist after submitting the form which I set its data in my model after submitting the form. I kindly appreciate of any help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working demo:

View(TestOperatorViewModel.cshtml):

```
   <form method="post" style="height: 4rem;">

        <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            region:
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRegionID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RegionId, "select")
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedRegionText)
                        </label>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <label>
                            Zone:
                            @* I change the dropdownlist *@
                            <select id="SelectedZoneID" name="SelectedZoneID">
                                <option value='0'>select</option>
                            </select>

                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedZoneText)


                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button>submit</button>
    </form>
@section scripts{
    <script>
     $("#SelectedRegionID")
            .change(function () {

                var id = $(this).val();
                $("#SelectedRegionText").attr("value", $("#SelectedRegionID option:selected").text());
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetZones", "Test")/' + id, function (data) {
                    //delete the options of $("#SelectedZoneID") and add new options
                    $("#SelectedZoneID").empty();
                    $("#SelectedZoneID").append('<option value="0">select</option>');
                     $.each(data, function (value, text) {
                         $("#SelectedZoneID").append('<option value="' + value + '">' + text.text + '</option>');
                });
        });
            });
        $("#SelectedZoneID").change(function () {
            $("#SelectedZoneText").attr("value", $("#SelectedZoneID option:selected").text());
        })
    </script>
}
```

Controller(I use fake data to test,ControllerName is `TestController`):

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult TestOperatorViewModel() 
        {
            List<SelectListItem> RegionId = new List<SelectListItem>();
            RegionId.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "r1", Text = "id1" });
            RegionId.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "r2", Text = "id2" });
            RegionId.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "r3", Text = "id3" });
            ViewBag.RegionId = RegionId;
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult TestOperatorViewModel(OperatorViewModel operatorViewModel)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        public JsonResult GetZones(string ID)
        {


            List<SelectListItem> ZoneList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            ZoneList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "one"+ID });
            ZoneList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "two"+ID });
            ZoneList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "three"+ID });
            return Json(ZoneList);
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Then how can I send the selectedZoneID to the controller in order to get its value?

Comment: I have updated my answer,when click the button,you can get a OperatorViewModel with selected data in controller.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used your new code but it doesn't populate data to the second selectlist. I'm also populating my second selectlist with ViewData that its data is filled in my controller so I changed the second selectlist like the following: <select name="m.SelectedZoneID" class="form-control statesSelect" asp-items="ViewBag.ZoneID">
                        <option value='0'>select</option>
                    </select>

Comment: I want to send it by OperatorViewModel.SelectedZoneID in order to keep its value in my controller. But the problem is in my Index method of my controller, SelectedZoneID is null after submitting the form

Comment: I want to keep the selected zone item after submitting the form.

Comment: I want to keep the selected zone item in selectlist after submitting the form

Comment: I don't understand why you say my code cannot ` populate data to the second selectlist`,when the first dropdownlist change,it will get relatedZones from controller action,and then `  $("#SelectedZoneID").empty(); $("#SelectedZoneID").append('<option value="0">select</option>');
                     $.each(data, function (value, text) {$("#SelectedZoneID").append('<option value="' + value + '">' + text.text + '</option>');`will add the related Zones to the selectlist.And in your code,`name="@Html.NameFor(c=>c.SelectedZoneID)"` ,press F12,you can see you also get `name="SelectedZoneID"` in html